# How to update Map's key with new value if the key exists?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a todoDate (Map<String, List> variable), and I add a key but sometimes the key already exists therefore nothing is added to the Map data type I want to add the value to the existing key but doesn't work.
**I have 2 textfields (each one has a controller) and a button:** addKey() functionality in the button's onPressed.

```dart
void addKey()
{
  for (var key in todoDate.keys) {
    final containsKey = todoDate.containsKey(key);
    
    if (containsKey) {
      todoDate.update(key, (value) =&gt; todoDate[key] = value);
    } else {
      // if key doesn't exist, create new key and value
      setState(() { todoDate[dateController.text.toTitleCase()] = [ taskController.text.toTitleCase() ]; });
    }
  }
}
```

However it doesn't work, I think the I wrote the update method wrong so how do I do that correct?

Comment: in the `else` condition you use `setState` , so i assume your variable not update on UI. 
so you have to `setState` on `if` condition too. then your UI will updated with new value

Answer (score 3):

`update` function already has a parameter called `ifAbsent`. So what you need is just passing the new value to the update and to the `ifAbsent`.
your function would look like this:

```
void addKey(key,newValue) {
    todoDate.update(key, (value) => newValue,ifAbsent: () => newValue);
}
```